# Lots of finalizations when using AseClient

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, ado.net, sybase, finalizer

We have high volume .Net Framework API's that execute stored procedures on Sybase, using the AseClient driver (Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll version 16.0.2.6).

I have run PerfView on a production machine and I see enormous numbers of *Finalized Object Counts* (open the PerfView dumpfile -> Memory Group -> GCStats menu item) for given services:
[image: Finalized Object Counts]

This puts a big strain on the .Net GC, for many services that connect to Sybase we see GEN1 and GEN2 collections.

For the worst performing service the database logic looks like:

```
using (var connection = new AseConnection(ConnectionString)) {
using (var command = new AseCommand("exampleproc", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, Connection = connection })
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var nextResult = true;

        while (nextResult)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Put logic here..
            }

            nextResult = dr.NextResult();
        }
    }
}}
```

Can I do something to prevent late finalization of the resources and as a result have less GC pauses?

Comment: connection/command pool with the controller picking up the next one idle. In this case you will only be recycling the cursors, while keeping a small connection pool open most of the time. That's for starters.

Comment: Why pool objects that hold no resources like commands?

Comment: you are recycling them through GC, which adds to the commotion, me thinks, based on your own table you posted